# SPGridview Filters date formatting issue

Tags: filter, spgridview

I have an issue with spgridview filters, in my grid view i have column that contains start date and i have to display date in "yyyy-MMM-dd" format, i am able to do this with the custom itemtemplate but it still showing date in filters as "mm/dd/yyyy" format.

Any idea how to achieve this, its very urgent for me.

waiting for your response !!

THANKS,
CHAMPION

Answer (score 1):

I remember I also had this problem a while ago. And if I remember correctly, the only way to change the format of the date in the filter is to change the regional settings of the site.

Go to Site Actions -> Site Settings and under Site Administration you will find Regional Settings. Here you can change under Locale how your date is formatted. For example, to achieve YYYY.MM.DD you can choose the Hungarian locale. But be careful as this change will affect other aspects of your site as well.

I hope this helped you a little.

Comment: Hi Norbert,
Thanks for your response, as we don't have the access to the production site and we don't know what will be the impact of this change, so it doesn't seem feasible to me. Any other option which can be implemented in webpart.

Thanks
CHAMPION